# ¿Como hacer un append de 2 TClientDataSet que tienen registros duplicados en delphi?

Tags: delphi

Buen dia, estoy tratando de hacer un append de un TClientDataSet con otro, pero puede ser que estos 2 dataset tengan registros iguales. El problema es que esto me genera un error de Key violation al intentar hacer el append, pero necesito tener los 2 registros aunque sean duplicados. Me gustaria agregarle un campo al dataset e indicarle que es parte de la Primary key, pero no se como hacerlo.

Este es el codigo que utilizo para crear el TClientDataSet:

```
//Esta funcion recibe como parametro ,la query y un boolean, y devuelve un TClientDataSet

function fxQueryToCDS(pqQuery : TFXQuery; pbFreeQuery : Boolean = true) : TClientDataSet;
var
  dspCDS : TDataSetProvider;
begin
  dspCDS := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
  Result := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);

  dspCDS.DataSet := pqQuery;
  try
    Result.Data := dspCDS.data;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(dspCDS);

    if pbFreeQuery then
      FreeAndNil(pqQuery);

  end;
  Result.Open;
end;
```

Esta es una parte del codigo, es en la cual me da el Key violation:

```
cdsConsulta1Principal := fxQueryToCDS(query1);
cdsConsulta1Sucursal := fxQueryToCDS(query2);
cdsConsulta1Principal.AppendData(cdsConsulta1Sucursal.Data, False);//aca da key violation si hay registros iguales.
cdsConsulta1Principal.MergeChangeLog;
```

Si o si necesito hacer hacer el append de los registros, aunque esten duplicados, porque los datos vienen de 2 bases de datos distintas, pero no se me ocurre como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ClientDataSet se basa en la información proveída por los campos del dataset subyacente para determinar la llave del ClientDataSet. Agregar un campo nuevo, por la forma en la que estás asignando los datos, puede resultar un poco más complicado.

Mi primer sugerencia, dado que quieres permitir duplicados, es que podrías dejar al ClientDataSet receptor de los datos sin llave alguna. Aún serías capaz de llevar cambios de vuelta a una base de datos valiéndote en los valores de los campos o definiendo una nueva llave más adelante.

Para lograr dejar al ClientDataSet sin llave alguna, suponiendo que tus querys tienen campos persistentes, en tiempo de diseño o antes de abrir el query toma los campos llave del mismo y asegúrate que su propiedad `ProviderFlags` no incluya el flag `[pfInKey]`, por ejemplo:

```
  query1.FieldByName('CampoLlave').ProviderFlags := query1.FieldByName('CampoLlave').ProviderFlags - [pfInKey];
  query1.Open;
```

Si no sabes cuales son los campos llave o quieres tratarlo de manera genérica, puedes hacer un recorrido por todos los campos del query:

```
  for I := 0 to query1.Fields.Count - 1 do
    query1.Fields[I].ProviderFlags := query1.Fields[I].ProviderFlags - [pfInKey];
  query1.Open;
```